# loading millions of marker based on clustering ajax

Tags: php, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have a website where 1 millions of marker are loaded when loading a page and i am fetching all the listing in one time with there image so it make page too heavy and take 1 min or long for loading a page. So i want to load all the listing based on ajax when i click on cluster so i will load the listing inside only. i didn't find any documention of google map cluster v3 for the loading marker based on ajax. I don't want the other solution like fusion table and other. i want like this [click here](http://vanfun.com/map-0.aspx)

I create the json format for listing on my controller and parse the json format to the map.

these are my [controller](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85b514274ef72114fc79) and [js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e35a5bb10d5e5d0612f1).

please help how to achieve this type of functionlity.

Comment: What have you tried (and can you give a code sample)? What is your specific problem?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter now i put the code so can you tell me how to load 1 millions of property on map .

Comment: Linking to code on github is not what you should be doing - please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO aims to be a reference site, and should contain the complete problem (and its answers) without relying on external resources as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may need some kind of backend clustering.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

Read the section "Fusion Tables"

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how this would help?

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/985370/map.zip you can check my code her e and i want it on ajax lattitude and lognitude bound